# How to only allow certain PowerShell commands to be run on PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

We want to give an user access to the Skype Powershell module to check some Skype for Business setting, but we only want to allow him to run certain specific PowerShell command and block other non-specified commands. For example, if we only want the user to run PowerShell command " Get-CsOnlineUser", the user can only run that command and could not use any other commands. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: How about using scheduled tasks without a trigger? Set them to run as an admin user, and get your user to start them from the Task Scheduler.

Comment: i think you want to look at `powershell constrained endpoint` or at `powershell Just Enough Administration`.